# Renaming using terminal and regexp to remove leading numbers from filenames

Tags: shell, regular-expression, rename, macintosh

I want the following files to be renamed removing the sequence numbers.

`01 X.mp3` to `X.mp3`

`02 Add Me In.mp3` to `Add Me In.mp3`

I am trying with the below rename command.

```
rename -v -n 's/^\d+\s*([a-z]+\.mp3)$/$1\.mp3/' *.mp3
```

Running this command gives me this error:

```
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18'; s/^\d+\s*([a-z]+\.mp3)$/$1\.mp3/ }
```

Comment: I tried it on my machine, didn't get the error.. but your command could be improved to `rename -v -n 's/^\d+\s*//' *.mp3` to get your desired result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why that error would occur. In fact, I am reasonably certain there were more lines to the error than you show; for one thing, there's no actual error message.

However, that regular expression won't actually match either of your example files. You are using `[a-z]+\.mp3` which will only match lower case letters and, since you're matching all the way to the extension, it will only match files whose name consists of *only* lower case letters after the numbers and space you want to remove. You could instead match `[a-zA-Z]` or use `s///i` to make the match case insensitive, but it would be a better idea to not match the rest of the word at all. You just want to remove the digits and whitespace from the beginning, so just match those:

```
rename -vn 's/^\d+\s+//' *mp3
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution using [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
for i in *.mp3 ; do mv "$i" "${i#"${i%%[!0-9 ]*}"}" ; done
```

- `${i%%[!0-9 ]*}` deletes from first non-digit/non-space character till end.
- Remaining characters are passed to `${i#` which then deletes them from beginning of `i` variable resulting in desired file name without starting digits and space

Comment: Values on the right side of the `#` are read as **patterns**, so, if `i` may contain pattern special characters (*, ?, [) its value should be (also) quoted:  `"${i#"${i%%[!0-9 ]*}"}"`.

Comment: @Isaac thanks, edited the answer.. although in this case, I think it isn't required because it will delete all the special characters

Comment: In this particular case, yes, the `${i%%[!0-9 ]*}` will remove all `*?[`, otoh quoting will cause no ill issue either. I believe that it is a good idea to fall into the habit of seeing `${var#" … "}` used in general.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `-n` will make it work. `-n` means "Just print the result instead of changing it".